# KeyNotFoundException on SaveChanges()

Tags: mysql, asp.net-mvc-3, visual-studio-2010, entity-framework

Okey so i'm trying to update information in my database from a form.
But when i call db.SaveShanges() i get KeyNotFoundException.
I'm using MVC3 and EF 4.1.
I use Controller->Service->Repositry->EF design pattern.

The callstack:

```
   at System.Collections.Generic.Dictionary`2.get_Item(TKey key)
   at System.Data.Objects.EntityEntry.UpdateComplexObjectSnapshot(StateManagerMemberMetadata member, Object userObject, Int32 ordinal, Object currentValue)
   at System.Data.Objects.EntityEntry.DetectChangesInProperties(Boolean detectOnlyComplexProperties)
   at System.Data.Objects.ObjectStateManager.DetectChangesInScalarAndComplexProperties(IList`1 entries)
   at System.Data.Objects.ObjectStateManager.DetectChanges()
   at System.Data.Objects.ObjectContext.DetectChanges()
   at System.Data.Entity.Internal.InternalContext.DetectChanges(Boolean force)
   at System.Data.Entity.Internal.InternalContext.GetStateEntries(Func`2 predicate)
   at System.Data.Entity.Internal.InternalContext.GetStateEntries()
   at System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.DbChangeTracker.Entries()
   at System.Data.Entity.DbContext.GetValidationErrors()
   at System.Data.Entity.Internal.InternalContext.SaveChanges()
   at System.Data.Entity.Internal.LazyInternalContext.SaveChanges()
   at System.Data.Entity.DbContext.SaveChanges()
```

My repositrory db is a dbContext with a DbSet for the model i'm using.

```
public bool Save()
{
    try
    {
        db.SaveChanges();
    }
    catch(Exception e)
    {
        return false;
    }
    return true;
}
```

My Service that calls the repository

```
public bool UpdateUserInformationFromSettingsModel(UserSettingsModel model)
{

    int userInfoID = _profile.GetUserInformationID(model.userName);
    UserInformation userInfo = _repository.Get(userInfoID);
    if (userInfo == null)
    {
        return false;
    }
    userInfo.firstName = model.firstName;
    userInfo.lastName = model.lastName;
    userInfo.phone = model.phone;
    userInfo.invoiceReciever = model.invoiceReciever;
    userInfo.invoiceAddress = model.invoiceAddress;
    userInfo.address = model.address;
    userInfo.preferedLanguage = model.preferedLanguage;
    bool saveSuccess = _repository.Save();
    if(!saveSuccess)
    {
        return false;
    }

    return true;
}
```

My controller

```
        [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult Edit(UserSettingsModel model)
    {
        if(ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            if (_userService.UpdateUserInformationFromSettingsModel(model))
            {
                return RedirectToAction("Settings");
            }
            ModelState.AddModelError("", GuiText.editSettingsError);
        }
        return View(model);
    }
```

The UserInformation Model

```
public class UserInformation
{
    public int ID { get; set; }
    public string firstName { get; set; }
    public string lastName { get; set; }
    public string phone { get; set; }
    public string invoiceSendOption { get; set; }
    public string invoiceReciever { get; set; }
    public Address invoiceAddress { get; set; }
    public Address address { get; set; }
    public string preferedLanguage { get; set; }
    public string confirmCode { get; set; }
    public UserSiteSettings siteSettings { get; set; }


    public UserInformation()
    {
        firstName = "";
        lastName = "";
        phone = "";
        invoiceSendOption = "";
        invoiceReciever = "";
        invoiceAddress = new Address();
        address = new Address();
        preferedLanguage = "";
        confirmCode = "";
        siteSettings = new UserSiteSettings();
    }
```

The UserSettingsModel

```
    public class UserSettingsModel
{
    public string userName { get; set; }
    [Display(Name = "name", ResourceType=typeof(GuiText))]
    public string firstName { get; set; }
    public string lastName { get; set; }
    [Display(Name = "phone", ResourceType = typeof(GuiText))]
    public string phone { get; set; }
    [Display(Name = "invoiceInfo", ResourceType = typeof(GuiText))]
    public string invoiceReciever { get; set; }
    public Address invoiceAddress { get; set; }
    [Display(Name = "address", ResourceType = typeof(GuiText))]
    public Address address { get; set; }
    [Display(Name = "prefLang", ResourceType = typeof(GuiText))]
    public string preferedLanguage { get; set; }
    public List<SelectListItem> preferedLanguageList { get; set; }
```

I have checked the variables in debugger and it all seems to be ok.

I'm using MySql connector v6.5.4.

So anyone got any ideas what the problem might be?

Comment: Is your Get method setting the ID on the userinfo?

Comment: yes the userInfo i get have a ID set.

Comment: Any chance of seeing the model and any special mappings you have on it?

Comment: So now i have added the UserInformation model and the UserSettingsModel viewModel

Comment: Do the address entities have their Ids and all mandatory fields set? how about the mandatory fields on the userinformation?

Comment: The address dont have any ID property, all the fields goes into the same table. But yes i have checked all the fields and they are all filled with the right data.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After some days of frustration and searching i found the problem.
I used a custom made equals method in my UserInformation and Address class. That caused the problems. Now i have removed it and changed my Unit Tests to work in another way.